# How do I log to a file when an error occurs while using the question mark (?) operator?

Tags: error-handling, rust, error-logging

Motivation: I want to log file name, line number, function name, error code, etc to help analyze errors

Rust has `?` to do error handling. I want to log info to a file if there is an error in `?`. How to achieve this?

Code:

```
let a = do_some_function_may_return_error()?;   // Does it auto log the error info when error occurs?
let b = a.do_another_function_may_return_error()?; // Does it auto log the error info when error occurs?
```

Comment: You might be interested by the [tracing framework](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing), and in particular by annotating the relevant functions with the [tracing attributes](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/tree/master/tracing-attributes).

Comment: Thx. If `?` is not possible to customized. I think I want to implement a macro like `try` 
 on top of the tracing framework. Then I can log file name, line number, error code, etc to help analyze errors

Answer (score 5):

No, this does not happen, and probably **cannot** for multiple reasons:

1. Rust the language is intended to run on systems that don't even have the *concept* of files, so requiring it for something as fundamental as `?` would be a non-starter.
2. `?` can be used for other types besides `Result`, such as `Option` or `Poll`. Should those be logged to a file?
3. How would you even configure the file to log to?
4. The error type of `Result` doesn't guarantee that it can be formatted as text.

Instead, I'd add an *extension trait*:

```
trait LogExt {
    fn log(self) -> Self;
}

impl<T, E> LogExt for Result<T, E>
where
    E: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn log(self) -> Self {
        if let Err(e) = &self {
            eprintln!("An error happened: {}", e);
        }
        self
    }
}
```

This would be used before each `?`:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    fails().log()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn fails() -> Result<(), String> {
    Err("Oh no!".into())
}
```

Comment: I don't think points 1 and 3 are valid. For example, Rust allows you to change the default allocator which changes the behavior of `box foo`, even though Rust doesn't require an allocator. Nothing would prevent the language from allowing to configure a “default error handler” to change the behavior of `foo?`. It's just not implemented, and mostly never will, because logging every single error would most likely not be useful.

Comment: Acturally I want to log file name, line number, function name, error code, etc to help analyze errors. For point 4 (error type of Result doesn't guarantee that it can be formatted as text.), I think can log infos other than error code